# Are CyanogenMod questions accepted on Android SE?

Tags: discussion

There is no mention of CyanogenMod in FAQ, and there is no policy about it. There are only 231 questions related to it, most of them are about rooting and flashing. Are CyanogenMod related questions welcome to http://android.stackexchange.com?

Comment: "Only" 231?  I think it's safe to say that anything on this site with hundreds of (open) questions is on-topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's a question about installing, configuring, or otherwise **using** CyanogenMod, then yes, that's perfectly acceptable. CM is Android, just like any other ROM is, so end-user questions about CM are no diferent than end-user questions about other ROMs.

If you have a question about **compiling** (or otherwise modifying the source of) CyanogenMod then it would be out-of-scope for this site.

Comment: how about compiling without any modifications? Some power users might want, for various reasons, to use a specific revision from the version control that are not officially released or perhaps one of the cloned trees might have features or fixes that have not been merged into the official tree (or even, will never be integrated). I'd say those are still in the domain of what a power user might want to do.

Comment: @LieRyan: Historically, questions along those lines have ended up closed (for example: [How to build / compile su from source?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18857)) which I why I stated it that way. I'd have no real problems myself with questions simply about building it as long as the community as a whole seems to agree. I personally build CM from source for several of my devices, just as you note, without making any modifications. That's not a decision I (or anyone) will make unilaterally, though.

Comment: CM has a long history and a huge install base: 2.3M and growing. Ignoring those users wouldn't be good for the site. http://stats.cyanogenmod.com/